# Is vue.$emit( 'event' ) processed synchronously?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-listener, eventemitter, onblur

I thought Vue would execute the "this.$emit( 'event' );" asynchrounusly. But the following code seems to be executed synchrounously

```
onBlur() {
  console.log( 'onBlur - before emit' );
  this.$emit( 'test' ); // bound to a function that logs 'test called'
  console.log( 'onBlur - after emit' );
}
```

In the console I see

```
onBlur - before emit
test called
onBlur - after emit
```

And if I return a value from the called event-Listener, the value can be accassed in the onBlur method.
But are emitted events in vue always executed synchronously?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's not just Vue, event buses in JS are generally sync, including built-in `Event`. Things that use them like DOM may be not.